# How to display details using View in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am working on the application where we needs to display all logs details using a view. Here is my Action Method:

```
public ActionResult GetLogs()
        {
            string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnString"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Get_AccessLog";
            cnn.Open();
            object o = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return View("GetLogs");
        }
```

[image]

**Model**:

```
public class GetLogs
    {
        [Display(Name = "Log Activity Id")]
        public int LogActivityId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Log Activity Name")]
        public string LogActivityName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Log Activity Desc")]
        public string LogActivityDesc { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

**View**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LogActivityId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LogActivityName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LogActivityDesc)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.LogActivityId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogActivityName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogActivityDesc)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

[image].

When I am running this application I am getting this exception.

[image].

Can anyone help me why I am getting this exception?

Here is the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Get_AccessLog`()
BEGIN
SELECT 
   LogActivityId,
   LogActivityName,
   LogActivityDesc
FROM
    log_activity;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your error is because you need to pass the model to the View in the action method, so instead of `return View("GetLogs")`, use `return View("GetLogs", yourModel);`. You also need to use a `DataReader` on your Command so you can read all records and covert the data row into a `GetLogs` object. At the moment calling `ExecuteScalar()` on something you expect to return 3 columns and many rows makes no sense

Comment: Also please [Don't post images of code and errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1048425), posting the actual code makes it much easier to help you

Comment: Thanks @GarethD. Could you please help me with changes in Action Method Like in which line I needs to make changes in public ActionResult GetLogs(){..}

Comment: When I am passing model name:public ActionResult GetLogs()
        {
            string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnString"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Get_AccessLog";
            cnn.Open();
            object o = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return View("GetLogs",GetLogs);
        }

Comment: I am getting error pointing to this line return View("GetLogs", "GetLogs");

Comment: Do I needs to use model name under "" or simply by name. When I am trying to use without "" am getting error.@GarethD

Comment: My view name is "Getlogs" and model name is also GetLogs.cs. @GarethD

Comment: If you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75754732/edit) with code as text rather than as images, so I can copy and paste bits out of it, then yes I can try and offer a solution that will work for you, but typing it out from scratch based on images is too time consuming (for me at least, someone else may wish to help

Comment: Can we connect though skype? If yes can I have your skype ID?

Comment: Here is my action method @GarethD.   public ActionResult GetLogs()
        {
            string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnString"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Get_AccessLog";
            cnn.Open();
            object o = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return View("GetLogs");
        }

Comment: @GarethD here is the model :  public class GetLogs
    {
        [Display(Name = "Log Activity Id")]
        public int LogActivityId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Log Activity Name")]
        public string LogActivityName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Log Activity Desc")]
        public string LogActivityDesc { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I have added code for Action method and model @GarethD.

Comment: I have updated the question with code in plain text as well.

Comment: @GarethD, based on the above code which you have shared, How we can separate those in BLL and DAL. I  mean in different layers?

Comment: Hi @GarethD, Could you please help me in how I can separate the Action method's code into separate layers like BLL(Business Logic layer) & DAL(Data Access Layer).? Kindly explain in details in accordance with the above example. I am doing it for the first time.

Comment: Hi @GarethD, Here is what I tried 1. Right clicked on Folder named (E_Record_Crew.BLL) and added new class and renamed it as GetLogs.cs. Now I am uncertain how to proceed further. I needs your valuable suggestion and explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @GarethD, I have tried to separate the code between DAL & BLL, but I needs your explanation. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Hi Rajnikant, If you have a new question please create a new question, but as it stands your question is too broad to answer, and I do not provide a free consulting service, I simply answer some questions here every now and then as a way of clearing my head during my paid for work. You should do some research reading a number of tutorials about application architecture, and if you have specific questions about areas you don't understand then ask a new question, but Stackoverflow is not the place to provide full tutorials on subjects as broad as this.

Comment: @GarethD. Good morning. in the implementation we are showing all the activity logs but how we can achieve the requirement in which we needs to display all the details like who created/uploaded/renamed/deleted the folders as logs. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Hi @GarethD. I needs small help in the above implementation, Could you please guide me here in implementing the same using data table please,

Answer (score 1):

Since your view is expecting a model of type `IEnumerable<GetLogs>` this is what you need to pass from your action method:

```
public ActionResult GetLogs()
{
    //set up your connection
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnString"].ConnectionString;
    using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    using var command = new MySqlCommand("Get_AccessLog", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
    connection.Open();
    
    // define a list to hold your records
    var data = new List<GetLogs>();
    using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    
    //loop through the reader (i.e. itenerate each row returned by your stored procedure
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Create a new log record based on the db row
        data.Add(new GetLogs()
        {
            LogActivityId = reader.GetInt32(0),
            LogActivityName = reader.GetString(1),
            LogActivityDesc = reader.GetString(2)
        });
    }
    //Return the view along with the logs
    return View("GetLogs", data);
}
```

I'd also note that if you use an object mapper like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper)<sup>1</sup> then you can remove a lot of code here, your method becomes

```
using Dapper;
...
public ActionResult GetLogs()
{
    //set up your connection
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnString"].ConnectionString;
    using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    var data = connection.Query<GetLogs>(sql: "Get_AccessLog", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    return View("GetLogs", data);
}
```

This is a more of a demonstration than a long term solution though, I would ideally recommend moving your data access to a separate layer, but there are entire books written on application architecture and best practices etc, so I won't even attempt to start here.

---

<sub>1. My personal preference, I have no affiliation and other micro ORMs are available</sub>

Comment: Let me try with your code. Thanks

Comment: Could you please help me in separating these concerns into BLL & DAL @Gareth? as I am doing it for the first time. Please help me as I am  eagerly would like to implement it in our application.

Comment: As I say, there are entire books written on the various ways of doing this, so I can't begin to answer properly in the space and time available here. I would suggest searching for tutorials and examples on this. I just [did a quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=service+layer+repository+pattern+c%23) and one of the top articles was [this one](https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-repository-service-pattern-with-dependency-injection-and-asp-net-core/) which helps explain how you might use repositories (DAL) and service layers.